# Forever-agent in request.js - how to check if it's working

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

recently, external server(REST API) told me to use Keep-alive for my request. That's great, since I use request.js(node 8) I found "forever" option:

`forever - set to true to use the forever-agent Note: Defaults to http(s).Agent({keepAlive:true}) in node 0.12+`

To test if it's working I created my own server in Node8 using Koa.js and Node script where I create array of 100 GET request to my server and after that, I Promise.all them.

However, I don't how can I check if it's using the same agent, if it's working correctly.

Do you have any ideas, how from client(or server) point of view I can check that?

Is keep-alive enough proof that all request for certain domain are using the same agent in 1 Node.js process?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229044/http-keep-alive-in-node-js

Comment: You could check the `socket` event on the client and check if they are the same for every request.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this works great for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client, you can try to capture the socket which is used to send the request using the `socket` event. You can  verify that they are using the same sockets on the client.

```
req.on("socket", function (socket) {
//if saved  socket is empty save it 
//else check if its using  the saved socket

}
```