# What is difference between keepAliveTimeout and connection timeout. How can I check keepAliveTimeout in headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, keep-alive, connection-timeout

Is there any difference between keepAliveTimeout and connection timeout ? I am using node.js with express. I have specified timeout as follows:

```
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`The server is running at http://localhost:3000/`);
});
app.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.setTimeout(60 * 1000);
});
```

Will above code change keepAliveTimeout ? In browser I am getting just `Connection: keep-alive` header in browser. How can I check keepAliveTimeout of my application ?

Answer (score 2):

Keep-Alive header can inform the client how long the server is willing to keep the connection open (timeout=N value) and how many requests you can do over the same connection (max=M) before the server will force a close of the connection.

Connection-TimeOut is when you request for connect and that takes mintue and don't get response so it give you Connection-TimeOut

Comment: How can I set keepAliveTimeout value (N) for my application. Is there a way to check current keepAliveTimeout value of the application. In header, I am getting just `Connection: keep-alive`, I am not getting keepAliveTimeout value.

Comment: you can specify timeout but server has no obligation to use that value. If server is configured with a different timeout, it will return its own Keep-Alive header.

Comment: That's exactly I want to ask that how we can set keepAliveTimeout value at node server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229044/http-keep-alive-in-node-js you can refer this

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parameters like this,

```
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`server on port ${port}`);
});
server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000;
server.headersTimeout = 66000;
```